# How to get onFocus() to fire with Selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test an `HTML` form using Selenium. The page authenticates the input data by using javascript's `onFocus()` event on each text field (which is an input tag in `HTML`). As such, my code needs to make sure `onFocus()` get fired whenever I interact with the text field, just as it would if a real user were filling out the form.

I would expect the following code to fire this event:

```
this.textfield.clear();
if (value != null) {
    this.textfield.sendKeys(value);
}
```

However, the `onFocus()` event doesn't fire. I've tried manually clicking the element

```
this.textfield.click()
```

But that also doesn't work. I've also tried using the Actions Class

```
this.textfield.clear();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(this.textfield).click().sendKeys(value.toString()).perform();
```

But this too hasn't given me any luck.

Is there any way in Selenium to ensure that the `onFocus()` event is executed?

Answer (score 2):

You can execute JavaScript in your browser session to explicitly fire onFocus(). This code is in C#, but there must be something similar in Java bindings too.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(string.Format("$('#{0}').onFocus()", elementId));
```